# How to successfully convert string to date type in AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, date, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert a date column of string type to date type.

I use the below query in AWS Athena:

```
SELECT a, b, date_parse(date_start, '%m-%d-%Y') AS date_start
FROM "database"."table"
```

If I add a limit 10 , it works. But when I try to do it to all records I get this error:
`INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "5/16/2020" is malformed at "/16/2020"`

All dates in the string type column look like this - 2/22/2020 and it converted that correctly. I don't understand why it won't do the same for the rest.

An additional question - I'm testing the conversion using the `SELECT` statement above -  if I figure this out what would be a next step? Can I do an `UPDATE TABLE` in AWS Athena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your date strings look like `'2-22-2020'` or `'2/22/2020'`?

If you have separator `'/'`, as shown in your error message, then you need to adapt your format specifier:

```
SELECT a, b, date_parse(date_start, '%m/%d/%Y') AS date_start
FROM "pg_orangeboydata"."kanopy"
```

You can also manage both formats at once:

```
SELECT a, b, date_parse(replace(date_start, '/', '-'), '%m-%d-%Y') AS date_start
FROM "pg_orangeboydata"."kanopy"
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly for that one issue! Would you know how to deal with a column that has some dates as '%m-%d-%Y' and others as %m-%d-%Y %H:%i'', if i don't consider it I get - `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "11-16-2019 20:16" is malformed at " 20:16"` and if I do then I get `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "9-7-2019" is too short`